# How to grab a thread that accesses a method?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I am working on a lock class to learn more on concurrency. What I am trying to do is create a queued lock. A thread calls lock, is added to a queue and when the lock is released and the thread is first in line of the queue, it will be able to continue.

What I would like to know is: is there a way I can grab the thread that is currently running the lock code or do I have to pass the thread object into the lock as a parameter?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The static method `Thread.currentThread` returns a reference to the currently executing `Thread` object.